# Adjust position of a lightbox without JS

Tags: html, css, position, lightbox

i have a lightbox image inside a div of a scrollable page.

I use everything in `%` so that every image adjusts to the screen size whether it is mobile or destkop.

The thing is that when I visit my site in mobile and I click in the lightbox, it appears at the bottom of the page! How can I set the position of the lightbox to appear in front of the clickable image?

My HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display:none;">
<label for="check">

<div id="biteme"><img src="biteme.png"></div>
 </label>

<label for="check">
    <div id="cover">
    <div id="box">
    <img src="promociones.png" width="80%">
    </div>
    </div>
    </label>
```

And my css is:

```
#biteme {
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

#check:checked ~ label #cover{
    display:block;
    background:none;
    }

#cover{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:none;
    display:none;
    }
    #box{
    position: inherit;
    top:313%;
    bottom:0;
    left:16%;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    border:none;
    opacity:0.9;
    background-color:transparent;
    background:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch them places that will work. You can use z-index to reorder boxes too.